# Huge update query fails with unknown column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` with MYSQL 5.6 working on three tables. This query throws this message:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column '`tborgexpdoc.intCodOrgExpDoc`' in
>   '`field list`'

Is it possible to use two or more tables?

```
INSERT INTO tbconsumidor 
select tbconsumidor.intCodConsumidor,
    case when tbconsumidor.strNome = '' then null else left(tbconsumidor.strNome,100) end strNome,
    case when tbconsumidor.strEndereco = '' then null else left(tbconsumidor.strEndereco,100) end strEndereco,
    left(tbconsumidor.strNumero,8) strNumero,
    case when tbconsumidor.strComplemento = '' then null else left(tbconsumidor.strComplemento,100) end strComplemento,
    case when tbconsumidor.strBairro = '' then null else left(tbconsumidor.strBairro,100) end strBairro,
    case when tbconsumidor.strCidade = '' then null else left(tbconsumidor.strCidade,100) end strCidade,
    case when tbconsumidor.strUF = '' then null else left(tbconsumidor.strUF,2) end strUF,
    case when  ((tbconsumidor.strCEP) regexp '^[[:digit:]]+$') = 1 then mig_sindecgo0008.tbconsumidor.strCEP end strCEP,
    case when tbconsumidor.strDDD = '' then null else left(tbconsumidor.strDDD,3) end strDDD,
    case when tbconsumidor.strFone = '' then null else left(tbconsumidor.strFone,40) end strFone,
    case when tbconsumidor.strEmail = '' then null else left(tbconsumidor.strEmail,100) end strEmail,
    case when tbconsumidor.strRG = '' then null else left(tbconsumidor.strRG,40) end strRG,
    case when tbconsumidor.strCPF = '' then null else replace(replace(replace(tbconsumidor.strCPF,'.',''),'-',''),'/','') end strCPF,
    case when tbconsumidor.strOutroDoc = '' then null else left(tbconsumidor.strOutroDoc,20) end strOutroDoc,
    tborgexpdoc.intCodOrgExpDoc as intCodOrgExpDoc,
                                case 
                                    when (replace(replace(replace(tbconsumidor.dtInclusao,'-',''),':',''),' ','')  regexp '^[[:digit:]]+$') = 1
                                    and tbconsumidor.dtInclusao > '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
                                    then tbconsumidor.dtInclusao
                                    else '1900-01-01 00:00:00'
                                end dtInclusao,
                                case 
                                    when (replace(replace(replace(tbconsumidor.dtAlteracao,'-',''),':',''),' ','')  regexp '^[[:digit:]]+$') = 1
                                    and tbconsumidor.dtAlteracao > '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
                                    then tbconsumidor.dtAlteracao
                                    else '1900-01-01 00:00:00'
                                end dtAlteracao,
                                case 
                                    when (replace(replace(replace(tbconsumidor.dtNascimento,'-',''),':',''),' ','')  regexp '^[[:digit:]]+$') = 1
                                    and tbconsumidor.dtNascimento > '0000-00-00'
                                    then tbconsumidor.dtNascimento
                                    else null
                                end dtNascimento,
                                tbconsumidor.intCodUsuarioCAD,
                                tbconsumidor.intCodUsuarioALT,
                                case when tbconsumidor.intDeficiente in (0,1) then tbconsumidor.intDeficiente else null end intDeficiente,
                                case when tbconsumidor.intGestante in (0,1) then tbconsumidor.intGestante else null end intGestante,
                                left(tbconsumidor.strSexo,1) strSexo,
                                tbestadocivil.intCodEstadoCivil,
                                case when tbconsumidor.strCodMunicipio in ('','0') then null else tbconsumidor.strCodMunicipio end strCodMunicipio,
                                case when tbconsumidor.strRGUf = '' then null else left(tbconsumidor.strRGUf,2) end strRGUf
                                from mig_sindecgo0008.tbconsumidor
                                    left join tbestadocivil
                                    on tbconsumidor.intCodEstadoCivil = tbestadocivil.intCodEstadoCivil
                                    left join tborgexpdoc
                                    on tbconsumidor.intCodOrgExpDoc = tborgexpdoc.intCodOrgExpDoc
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    tbconsumidor.intCodConsumidor = values(intCodConsumidor),
    tbconsumidor.strNome = values(strNome),
    tbconsumidor.strEndereco = values(strEndereco),
    tbconsumidor.strNumero = values(strNumero),
    tbconsumidor.strComplemento = values(strComplemento),
    tbconsumidor.strBairro = values(strBairro),
    tbconsumidor.strCidade = values(strCidade),
    tbconsumidor.strUF = values(strUF),
    tbconsumidor.strCEP = values(strCEP),
    tbconsumidor.strDDD = values(strDDD),
    tbconsumidor.strFone = values(strFone),
    tbconsumidor.strEmail = values(strEmail),
    tbconsumidor.strRG = values(strRG),
    tbconsumidor.strCPF = values(strCPF),
    tbconsumidor.strOutroDoc = values(strOutroDoc),
    tborgexpdoc.intCodOrgExpDoc = values(intCodOrgExpDoc),
    tbconsumidor.dtInclusao = values(dtInclusao),
    tbconsumidor.dtAlteracao = values(dtAlteracao),
    tbconsumidor.dtNascimento = values(dtNascimento),
    tbconsumidor.intCodUsuarioCAD = values(intCodUsuarioCAD),
    tbconsumidor.intCodUsuarioALT = values(intCodUsuarioCAD),
    tbconsumidor.intDeficiente = values(intDeficiente),
    tbconsumidor.intGestante = values(intGestante),
    tbconsumidor.strSexo = values(strSexo),
    tbestadocivil.intCodEstadoCivil = values(intCodEstadoCivil),
    tbconsumidor.strCodMunicipio = values(strCodMunicipio),
    tbconsumidor.strRGUf = values(strRGUf)
```

Comment: is this all one query? wow, it looks way too bulky.

Comment: You are inserting into `tbconsumidor` only, the assignments to other tables in the ON DUPLICATE KEY segment are not valid.

Comment: Yes! I'm trying to make this query more efficient!
I have 20 more queries like that!

Comment: I have intCodOrgExpDoc field (foreign key) in tbconsumidor!

Comment: But you are assigning to `tborgexpdoc.intCodOrgExpDoc` in the ON DUPLICATE KEY; which is not allowed.

Comment: Also, one big query is not necessarily "more efficient" than 10 (or even 100) smaller ones.

Comment: How can I use? Or need I use replace?

Comment: You cannot insert into multiple tables in a single query, nor can you insert into one and update others in a single query. (However, you can use TRIGGERs to cause an insert into one to insert/update others...but then you cannot update the one being inserted)

Comment: The problem is: I have 2 databases. The first one the tables don't have relationships (old big system) and in the second one I made all relationships (new big system), so I need migrate all data to the second one, but in the first one I have duplicate registries and it's cause conflict in primary, because I changed the primary key, now is intCodConsumidor. For example, I have three registries using the same intCodConsumidor (646).

Comment: You have FAR too much logic in your query. You appear to have crammed all of your input validation into SQL when it *should* be running in the application.

Comment: @sammitch, this query is to migrate all data to another database!

Comment: My fault! I putted ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE other tables (tborgexpdoc, tbestadocivil) but the correct is tbconsumidor. Thanks guys!

Comment: @SeyrSouza That is what I was saying.